# How to timestamp each line of a UNIX command that streams to stdout?

Tags: unix, command-line, stdout, unix-timestamp

Say I want to timestamp a command like `ping google.com` so that the output will look something like

```
[9:48:56]PING google.com (116.28.94.14): 56 data bytes
[9:48:55]64 bytes from 116.28.94.14: icmp_seq=0 ttl=54 time=13.118 ms
[9:48:57]64 bytes from 116.28.94.14: icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=13.943 ms
[9:48:58]64 bytes from 116.28.94.14: icmp_seq=2 ttl=54 time=19.103 ms
[9:48:59]64 bytes from 116.28.94.14: icmp_seq=3 ttl=54 time=12.854 ms
```

I've looked into fancy ways to use pipes and commands like `xarg` and `awk`, but I just can't get this right. Also, let's assume the environment I have doesn't allow me to use fancy things like `stdbuff` or `unbuff`. If possible, it'd be awesome to achieve this with the most unix-like approach possible. Thank you!

Comment: `man ping` says there is an option `-D`.. check it that helps

Comment: What are the "fancy ways" that you failed to use pipes and `awk`?  I'm usually quite happy with `perl -ne 'printf "[%s]: %s", scalar(localtime), $_'`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the absolute simplest and stupidest way to do it:

```
$ while read -r line ; do echo "$(date "+%H:%M:%S"): $line" ; done < <(while true ; do echo foo ; sleep 1 ; done)
00:07:08: foo
00:07:09: foo
00:07:10: foo
00:07:11: foo
00:07:12: foo
```

You can format the timestamp as you desire and run any command you'd like:

```
$ while read -r line ; do echo "$(date "+%s"): $line" ; done < <(ping google.com)
1472533833: PING google.com (216.58.216.78): 56 data bytes
1472533833: 64 bytes from 216.58.216.78: icmp_seq=0 ttl=55 time=11.391 ms
1472533834: 64 bytes from 216.58.216.78: icmp_seq=1 ttl=55 time=12.746 ms
1472533835: 64 bytes from 216.58.216.78: icmp_seq=2 ttl=55 time=10.912 ms
1472533836: 64 bytes from 216.58.216.78: icmp_seq=3 ttl=55 time=13.065 ms
1472533837: 64 bytes from 216.58.216.78: icmp_seq=4 ttl=55 time=10.684 ms
```

Here it as a shell function:

```
function logger {
  while read -r line ; do
    echo "$(date "+%H:%M:%S"): $line"
  done < <($*)
}
```

Weird commands and command output might break it, so some additional tweaking is likely required, but hopefully this is a good start for you.

EDIT: Some quick Googling turns up a thread with some great answers [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26728/prepending-a-timestamp-to-each-line-of-output-from-a-command).

Comment: You could smuggle the `$line` into the `date` format string; just escape any percent signs by doubling them.  `date +"%T: ${line//%/%%}"`

Answer (score 0):

The `ts` command (for "timestamp") in [moreutils](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/)<sup>1</sup> was made exactly for this.  To add timestamps to `ping` output formatted like your example you can use

```
ping google.com | ts '[%H:%M:%S]'
```

I don't know if this falls under "fancy ways to use pipes", but I'd say that it is a good unix-way of doing it in the sense that you're using a tool that [does one thing and does it well](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy#Do_One_Thing_and_Do_It_Well).

<sup><sup>1</sup>You can install moreutils in Debian/Ubuntu, for example,  with `sudo apt-get install moreutils`.</sup>